# Prolog parsing malfunctioning

Tags: prolog, dcg

My code takes an expression like `or(lit(true),lit(X)),X)` and outputs it as a list of lists.

```
 tocnf(Tree, Expr) :-
    trans(Tree ,Expr, []).

 trans(lit(X)) -->bbool(X).
 trans(or(lit(X1),lit(X2))) --> bconj(X1), bdisj(X2).
 trans(and(lit(X1),lit(X2))) --> bbool(X1), bconj(X2).

 bdisj(Conj) --> bconj(Conj).

 bconj(Bool) --> bbool(Bool).

 bbool(X) --> [[X]].
```

this code should take something like

```
tocnf(lit(X),X)
```

output it as

```
[[X]]
```

or

```
 tocnf(or(lit(true),lit(X)),X)
```

and output it as

```
[[true],[X]].
```

Question is why when I do

```
  tocnf(or(lit(true), and(lit(X),lit(true))),X)
```

it outputs

```
 false.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Preliminaries

First, a note on style: You should always use the `phrase/2` interface to access DCGs, so write `tocnf/2` as:

```
tocnf(Tree, Expr) :-
        phrase(trans(Tree), Expr).
```

Further, `tocnf/2` is a rather **imperative** name, since it implies a *direction* of use ("to" CNF). However, the **relation** also makes sense in other directions, for example to **generate** answers. Therefore, try to find a *better name*, that does justice to this general nature of Prolog. I leave this as an exercise.

## Declarative debugging

Now, on to your actual question. Apply **declarative debugging** to find the reason for the failure.

We start with the query you posted:

```
?- tocnf(or(lit(true), and(lit(X),lit(true))), X).
false.
```

This means that the program is unexpectedly **too specific**: It *fails* in a case we *expect* to succeed.

Now, we **generalize** the query, to find simpler cases that *still* fail. This is completely admissible because your program is written using the *monotonic* subset of Prolog, as is highly recommended to make declarative debugging applicable.

To generalize the query, I use **variables** instead of some subterms. For example:

```
?- tocnf(or(lit(_), and(lit(X),lit(true))), X).
false.
```

Aha! This *still fails*, and therefore every *more specific* query will *also* fail.

So, we proceed like this, using variables instead of some subterms:

```
?- tocnf(or(lit(_), and(lit(X),lit(_))), X).
false.

?- tocnf(or(_, and(lit(X),lit(_))), X).
false.

?- tocnf(or(_, and(_,lit(_))), X).
false.

?- tocnf(or(_, and(_,_)), X).
false.
```

All of these queries *also* fail.

Now, we take it just one step further:

```
?- tocnf(or(_, _), X).
X = [[_G793], [_G795]].
```

Aha! So we have found a case that *succeeds*, and one slightly more specific though still very simple case that fails:

```
?- tocnf(or(_, and(_,_)), X).
false.
```

This is the case I would start with: Think about *why* your relation does not work for terms of the form `or(_, and(_,_))`.

## Automated solution

A major attraction of pure monotonic Prolog is that the reasoning above can be **automated**:

> The *machine* should find the reason for the failure, so that we can focus on more important tasks.

One way to do this was generously made available by [Ulrich Neumerkel](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/).

To try it out, you need to install:

1. [**`library(diadem)`**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/diadem.pl) *and*
2. [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl).

Now, to recapitulate: We have found a query that unexpectedly *fails*. It was:

```
?- tocnf(or(lit(true), and(lit(X),lit(true))), X).
false.
```

To find a *reason* for this, we first load `library(diadem)`:

```
?- use_module(library(diadem)).
true.
```

Then, we repost the query with a slight twist:

```
?- tocnf(or(lit(true), and(lit(X),lit(true))), X).?Generalization.
```

That is, I have simply appended `?Generalization.` to the previous query.

In response, we get:

```
Generalization = tocnf(or(_, and(_, _)), _) .
```

Thus, `Generalization` is a *more general goal* that *still fails*. Since the Prolog program we are considering is completely pure and monotonic, we know that *every* more specific query will *also* fail. Therefore, I suggest you focus on this simpler and more general case, which was found *automatically* in this case, and is the same goal we also found manually after several steps.

Unexpected failure is a common issue when learning Prolog, and automated declarative debugging lets you quickly find the reasons.

Comment: thank you mate mat,that was helpful ,i will find my way around it .